# pandas selects a set of columns from a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I want to select a set of discrete columns from a dataframe (possibly put a new dataframe), and then convert the values of these columns into `str`, and so I can `sum` them and check for `duplicated`. For example,

```
      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
row1  s11   12    13    s14   15 
row2  s12   22    23    s24   NaN 
row3  s13   32    NaN   s34   35
```

`s11`, `s12`, `s13` are strings, `s14`, `s24`, `s34` are also strings, the other fields are numbers. Now I want to select columns `col1`, `col3`. `col5`, and convert the values in them to `str`, so that I can concatenate the values residing in these selected columns and compare for uniqueness/duplication. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `select_dtypes()` function:

```
In [69]: df
Out[69]:
     col1  col2  col3 col4  col5
row1  s11    12  13.0  s14  15.0
row2  s12    22  23.0  s24   NaN
row3  s13    32   NaN  s34  35.0
row4  s12    22  23.0  s24   NaN

In [70]: (df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
   ....:    .join(df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).astype(str))
   ....:    .duplicated()
   ....: )
Out[70]:
row1    False
row2    False
row3    False
row4     True
dtype: bool
```

Explanation:

```
In [71]: df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
Out[71]:
     col1 col4
row1  s11  s14
row2  s12  s24
row3  s13  s34
row4  s12  s24

In [73]: df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).astype(str)
Out[73]:
     col2  col3  col5
row1   12  13.0  15.0
row2   22  23.0   nan
row3   32   nan  35.0
row4   22  23.0   nan
```

but you don't actually need to concatenate your columns:

```
In [66]: df
Out[66]:
     col1  col2  col3 col4  col5
row1  s11    12  13.0  s14  15.0
row2  s12    22  23.0  s24   NaN
row3  s13    32   NaN  s34  35.0
row4  s12    22  23.0  s24   NaN

In [67]: df.duplicated()
Out[67]:
row1    False
row2    False
row3    False
row4     True
dtype: bool
```

**UPDATE:** "what if I only need col1, col3 and col5, and concatenate their values for duplicated?"

```
In [74]: df[['col1','col3','col5']].duplicated()
Out[74]:
row1    False
row2    False
row3    False
row4     True
dtype: bool
```

show unique only:

```
In [78]: df[['col1','col3','col5']].drop_duplicates()
Out[78]:
     col1  col3  col5
row1  s11  13.0  15.0
row2  s12  23.0   NaN
row3  s13   NaN  35.0
```

Comment: thx for reply, what if I only need `col1`, `col3` and `col5`, and concatenate their values for `duplicated`?

Comment: @daiyue, see "UPDATE:" in my answer